# What is the length of the yarn in a ball of yarn?

Tags: estimation, geometry, string, volume

The image https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ball_of_yarn_10.jpg shows a typical ball of yarn. Such a spherical ball of radius $R$ has a volume $4πR^3/3$. The radius of the yarn is $r$.

How long will the yarn be on average? The length will depend on the way the ball is formed. There will be air-filled space inside the ball. Therefore yarn length $L$ is surely smaller than $V/(πr^2)$. But what is its average length for an average ball? How can one determine this average length? Equivalently: how much air is contained in an average ball of yarn?

The yarn is assumed to be unstretchable but infinitely flexible. This is a question about statistical geometry. (This is not homework; the question is about the ensemble average over all possible balls of radius $R$.) Is there some method, maybe using random walks, to estimate an expectation value for the yarn length?

P.S. A few people continue to add the "homework" tag. This is not homework level. The level is more that of a master thesis.

Comment: *How can one determine this length?* I am guessing you are imposing certain restrictions on what we know about/can do with the ball? Otherwise I would just say unravel it and measure its length directly.

Comment: Test smaller balls of yarn to determine what fraction of the volume is used by the thread and then scale up.

Comment: I added the restrictions and details to the question.

Comment: If we're not going to do people's homework for them, why do you think we'd want to do your masters thesis for you? This isn't a general discussion forum where we can discuss methods and approaches without coming to a resolution. We provide specific answers to specific answerable questions. I'm voting to close the question as "too broad".

Comment: This is not my master thesis, nor did I say it was. I did mine many years ago. I asked a simple question, out of curiosity, because I did not find anything about it in the literature, and because I am unable to solve it by myself. I do not understand why you are angry. Real questions are difficult to solve. I am no Einstein, I am only a curious physicist.

Comment: Hi Gina Martelli. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: If the yarn is infinitely flexible, does that imply it can be bent with a radius of curvature smaller than its radius r?

Comment: It depends how you define the radius: if you define the radius of curvature as the radius of curvature of the centre line of the yarn, the answer is no; if you take the radius of curvature as that of the outer "skin" of the yarn, the answer is yes.

Comment: I repeat, this is neither homework, nor homework-like, nor home-work level. Neither following common sense, nor following this site's rules, definition or policies.

Comment: But you expect someone to present work on the level of a master's thesis here? Ain't gonna happen. You only get a few paragraphs.

Comment: Tis is rather a mathematics question. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/optimal-yarn-balls

Comment: The [tag:homework-and-exercises] does not denote the *level* of the question but the *type* of question. You're asking us for a calculation/estimation, which, as Qmechanics identifies, is aligned with the particular type this tag belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you that the question is tricky. To a first order approximation you might consider the packing density of the yarn to be equivalent to the hexagonal close packing of straight lengths of tube (that's the optimal) which is about 90%. However, if the yarn is wound at random you won't achieve that optimum density- sticking with the approximation of straight tubes, it will be as if the tubes are laid across each other at odd angles rather than being packed in an orderly way into a smaller volume.

I suspect it might be that crossing two pieces of twine at right angles results in the worst use of space, while wrapping them side by side provides the best use. If you could model the worst case, then perhaps you could find an expectation value for a random winding by supposing it is midway between the two.

Comment: This looks like a good start to me. One would then need the number of crossings on an average ball of yarn. That is not an easy question at all. (I posed a related, but different question on the site as well.) But in your approach, one would need an estimate for the number of crossings between adiacent "levels" - I have no idea how to estimate this number yet...